# How can I hold a SMTP connection open with smtplib and Python?

Tags: python, sockets, smtp, smtplib

I need to check the timeout of a SMTP-Server, but my socket just closes. What am I doing wrong? Here is my test for it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
import time
import datetime
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(1800)


now = time.time()
server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.connect('mx.foo.bar','25')
(code,resp) = server.docmd('NOOP')
then = time.time()

print then-now
```

Lets hope this works.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You connect, you send your mail, you disconnect. Why do you want to keep the connection open if you're not using it?

Comment: I'm trying to check RFC compliance. Python was suggested, instead of C for it's ease of use.

Answer (score 10):

Well, I haven't found any method to hold a smtp connection open with smtplib.

But, if you want to reuse a connection without closing (yes, opening a
connection takes time, 2-3 secs), you can test the connection first.
To do this, issue a NOOP command and test for status == 250. If not, then you
can open a connection and send out your mail. And you can choose to not quit() the connection until you are done.

```
import smtplib

def create_conn():
    conn = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    ...
    return conn

def is_connected(conn):
    try:
        status = conn.noop()[0]
    except:  # smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected
        status = -1
    return True if status == 250 else False
```

Comment: @Ethan- makes sense!

Comment: @trex Thanks. And it works great, I have been using it successfully without any issue for the last 2+ yrs.

Comment: This is a blocking method. Is it have timeout?

Comment: This works fine, Create a global variable smtp_connection and check is_connected(smtp_connection) in your create_conn function and it will reuse the same connection until its closed or timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are disconnecting?  When I run the above code against a postfix server I get:

```
connect: ('server', '25')
connect: ('ip.address', 25)
reply: '220 server ESMTP Postfix\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: nserver ESMTP Postfix
connect: server ESMTP Postfix
send: 'NOOP\r\n'
reply: '250 2.0.0 Ok\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.0.0 Ok
0.0531799793243
```

The docmd does not block, the server responses and the program exits.  I therefore disconnect when the program exits.

If I open a python command line and do:

```
>> import smtplib
>> server = smtplib.SMTP()
>> server.connect('server')
>> server.docmd('NOOP')
(250, '2.0.0 Ok')
>> ## let it sit for 5 minutes
>> server.docmd('NOOP')
(421, '4.4.2 server Error: timeout exceeded')
```

My logs confirm this:

```
Oct 20 10:45:35 [postfix/smtpd] connect from unknown[ip.address]
Oct 20 10:50:10 [postfix/smtpd] timeout after NOOP from unknown[ip.address]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your mail server settings - they may be cutting the connection.

Comment: It's happening with every MTA I checked. They get the command, return 220, then the connection is closed. Using telnet I get a timeout after 5 Minutes.